# anonymous mapping or file mapping?

Tags: c, linux

We can know whether a VMA (virtual memory area) exists in a particular region using `madvise`, if the return value is `-1` and `errno==ENOMEM`, then there is no VMA lying. Now I want to know that place is an annoymouns mapping or a file mapping, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `/proc/self/maps`.  It should tell you all you want about all regions.